# How can I make my x-axis begin at 0, and scale properly when I log it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

the question sort of sums it up. I'm working on a plot through ggplot 2 where I am trying to make the x-axis start at the number 0 while having previously logged it. Here is my code:

```
xbreaks <- c(0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000)
popbreaks <- rev(c(3, 10, 30, 100, 300)*1000000)

### Golden Scatter attempt
p1 <- ggplot(data = mainData,
            mapping = aes(x= gdpPercap,
                          y = lifeExp,
                          color = continent))

p <- p1 + goldenScatterCAtheme+  
      geom_point(alpha = 0.55, aes(size=pop)) +
      scale_x_log10(breaks= xbreaks,
                    labels= xbreaks/1000) +
      scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
      scale_size(breaks = popbreaks) +
      labs(x = "GDP per Capita", y = "Life Expectancy in Years")
      
p <- p + guides(size = FALSE)
#p <- p + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,NA))
      
width <- 7
ggsave("ggScatterHw1.pdf", width = width, height = width/1.618)
```

Here is the goldenScatterCAtheme code:

```
goldenScatterCAtheme <- theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
  aspect.ratio = ((1 + sqrt(5))/2)^(-1),
  axis.ticks.length = unit(0.5, "char"),
  #Horizontal
  axis.line.x.top = element_line(size = 0.1),
  axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(size = 0.1),
  axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 0.1),
  axis.text.x = element_text(color = "gray45", size = 12),
  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, margin = margin(t = 7.5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
  #Vertical
  axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = 0.1),
  axis.text.y = element_text(color = "gray45", size = 12, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 12, margin = margin(t = 0, r = 7.5, b = 0, l = 0)),
  #Legend
  legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA, color = NA),
  #GridLines
  panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "gray95", size = 0.2),
  panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray95", size = 0.2),
  #Faceting
  strip.background = element_blank(),
  strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
  strip.text.y = element_blank(),
  strip.placement = "outside",
  panel.spacing.x = unit(1.25, "lines"),
  panel.spacing.y = unit(1, "lines")
)
class(goldenScatterCAtheme)
```

Data used is from Gapminder for GDP per Capita and Life Expectancy.

This is what the graph looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: This is about math. Just try `log10(0)`, you will see the answer is `-Inf`. So what do you mean by "scale properly?". In other words you cannot have zero when using a log scale. In any case, please, in general include in your question a minimum example that demonstartes the problem and can be run by those you hope will provide an answer.

Comment: Understood! I took your advice and changed my approach to the problem, thank you!

Comment: In this case, I did not realize initially that the gapminder data are in the 'gapminder' package... I prefer to include the loading of packages in the example code/reprex, although not everybody does it.

Answer (score 3):

I like `pseudo_log_trans` b/c it combines a signed log scale with a linear scale, transitioning around +/- the `sigma` parameter. While it creates some distortion, it allows for depicting 0 (and even negative numbers), and labeling can clarify interpretation.

In the case below, I use `trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans()` instead of `trans = "pseudo_log"` so that I can access the `sigma` parameter to specify that the transition from linear to log should be around 500 (ie 0.5 on the labeled scale), which results in nearly linear scaling between 0 / 0.3 / 1, while preserving a good spread of the data for legibility across larger values.

```
xbreaks <- c(0, 300, 1000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000)
ggplot(gapminder::gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.55, aes(size=pop)) +
    scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 500),
                       limits = c(0, 30000),
                     breaks = xbreaks, labels = ~.x/1e3) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_size(breaks = popbreaks, guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "GDP per Capita", y = "Life Expectancy in Years") +
  goldenScatterCAtheme
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `log1p` or `pseudo_log` transform. However, this makes for a lot of wasted space on your plot and is a bit dubious from a mathematical / data viz perspective (0 would be *infinitely* far to the left on a properly log-scaled plot)

```r
ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.55, aes(size=pop)) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log1p", limits = c(0, 50000),
                     breaks = xbreaks, labels = ~.x/1e3) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  scale_size(breaks = popbreaks, guide = "none") +
  labs(x = "GDP per Capita", y = "Life Expectancy in Years") +
  goldenScatterCAtheme
```

[image]